# Struts2 - How to use the Struts2 Annotations?

Tags: struts2, annotations

I'm trying to implement the Struts 2 Annotations in my project, but I don't know how.

I added the convention-plugin v 2.1.8.1 to my **pom**

I modified the **web.xml**

```
...
  <init-param>
    <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.struts.helloworld.action</param-value>
  </init-param>
...
```

My Action

```
package org.apache.struts.helloworld.action;

import org.apache.struts.helloworld.model.MessageStore;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;


@Results({
  @Result(name="success", location="HelloWorld.jsp")
})

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        messageStore = new MessageStore() ;     return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The jsp page from where I'm trying to use my action.

```
 <body>
<h1>Welcome To Struts 2!</h1>
<p><a href="<s:url action='helloWorld'/>">Hello World</a></p>
</body>
```

When I press the link associated to the action **helloWorld**, but it's sends me to the exactly the same page. So, from index.jsp, it's sends to index.jsp.

The way it should behave: it should send me to **HelloWorld.jsp**.

I uploaded the project (a very simple HelloWorld app) to FileFront, maybe someone sees where is the problem. http://www.filefront.com/16364385/Hello_World.zip

Answer (score 1):

Convention uses a different convention to convert CamelCaseAction names to url's and jsp's names. If you are using Convention's defaults, I believe you should have used the following names:

ActionClass: HelloWorldAction.java

JSP: hello-world.jsp

Action: hello-world

Also, notice that by default convention will look for your JSPs on WEB-INF/content . The documentation is a bit shallow, you have to understand by the examples, but you can consult all default values there: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I havent used Struts2 with annotations (which Struts2 version? are you following some tutorial or doc?) .  But should not that *location* attribute (in the [Result annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/result-annotation.html)) be instead *value* ?

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs say? Have you tried using /HelloWorld.jsp for "success". I think that struts framework does not find the resource and is loading the same page.

When you use /HelloWorld.jsp, hopefully you will see the result page.